# Why more memory on hadoop map task make mapreduce job slower?

Tags: performance, hadoop, memory, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I want to ask. Why if I configured on mapred-site.xml in mapreduce.map/reduce.memory.mb and mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts to bigger value than default value make my job slower?

But If I configured it too low, then I'll get task failed. And I think on this condition, my memory configuration on hadoop is not necessary...

Can you give me an explanation?

Comment: How did you measure it? And what was the difference?

Comment: I measure it with running the same aplication but with the different memory configuration. The timer says that the larger memory the slower process , what do you think?

Comment: I think that we are missing some details, like what algorithm are you testing, how many nodes are there in the cluster, number of mappers, etc.

Comment: and I think that if you would repeat your experiment a hundred times, your variance of your meausures would be too large to get a meaningful result. So either attach some reliable data and your benchmark code, or leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

What might be happening in your environment is, when you increase values of the `mapreduce.map/reduce.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts` configurations to upper bound, it actually reduces the number of containers allowed to execute Map/Reduce task in every node thus eventually causes the slowness in the over all job time.

If you have 2 nodes, each with 25 GB of free ram , and say you configured the  `mapreduce.map/reduce.memory.mb` as 4 GB, then you might get atleast 6 containers on every node, totally it is 12. So you would get a chance of running 12 mapper/reducer tasks in parallel.

In case if you configure `mapreduce.map/reduce.memory.mb`  as 10 GB , then you might get only 2 containers on every node , totally it would be 4 containers to execute your mapper/reducer tasks in parallel. So the mapper/reducer tasks would mostly run in sequence due to lack of free containers, thus causes a delay in the over all job completion time.

You should justify the approprite value for the configuration with considering the resources available and the amount of resources required for the Map/Reduce containers according to your environment. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @kenny, were you able to get the clarification for this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

you can allocate memory for map/reduce containers based on two factors

1. available memory per each Datanode
2. total number of cores(vcores) you have.

try to create number of containers equivalent to number of cores you have in each detained. ( including hyper threading)
for example if you have 10 physical core ( 20 cores including hyper threading)

so total number containers you can plan is 19 ( leaving 1 core for other processes)

assume that you have 'X' GB Ram in each data node, then

leave some memory(assume Y GB) for other processes (heap) like, Datanode, Node Manager,Region server ,etc

Now memory available for YARN is X -Y = Z

Memory for Map container = Y/number of containers per node
Memory for Reduce container = Y/(2 * number of containers per node)